# Debug coded WorkflowServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-services

Is it possible to debug a coded Windows Workflow .Net 4.0.1 self-hosted WorkflowServiceHost?
I have

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

set in the app.config file. However, whenever I set a break point, the debugger stops at the point when the WorkflowServiceHost object is being constructed and not when an individual workflow instance reaches the break point.

By "coded" I mean the workflow is specified in C# instead of in the visual designer.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been in similar position with a variety of Flow chart and sequential workflows hosted in different containers. I found that using the Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting framework made my life a lot easier when it came to testing workflows. The library is available as a nuGet package. Comple details [here](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview)

It makes it very easy to run workflows in "test hosts" which are special classes that provide the ability to run workflows as they would normally run in  workflowinvoker, workflowservicehost etc. but offer a vast array of features that allow you to debug, trace your workflows.

Getting started is easy, loads of samples already provided (including the samples to test workflow service hosts hosted workflows).

I will highly recommend using this library, there is hardly a learning curve and it makes it very easy to test workflows.

Hope this helps.

One caveat though, make sure you have .NET framework 4 Platform Update 1 installed if you plan to use it. More details on this update here available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11705)

Comment: Thanks. Can the WorkflowServiceTestHost handle coded workflows as well as xamlx files?

Comment: Theoretically it can handle coded workflows and xamlx files but it is a bit tricky to make it work with WFs that don't have Send/Receive activities. I am actually blogging about this on my blog nikgupta.net as we recently did this. If you need help in achieving this reply back here or on my blog and I can work with you on that.

Comment: Since I'm using WorkflowServiceHosts, the workflows have Send/Receives activities. I know there is a way to convert coded workflows to xamlx, but it would involve eliminating/modifying some lambda's since they cannot be directly converted. I'm interested in reading your blog once the article is up.

Comment: I see your concern. The article might take a week to go online but bear with me. I will strive to upload sample code with the article as well to provide an end to end demo.

Comment: I didn't have the time to write the whole article but I have uploaded a sample application to show how this can be done. Hope that helps! The URL is http://www.nikgupta.net/2012/08/wfs-in-workflowservicehost/

Answer (score 1):

Is your Workflow dll is located in Different Project ?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483186.aspx) says

> If a workflow host application and workflow DLL are located in
>   different Visual Studio projects, for example, when you are using a
>   workflow activity library, you must set the workflow DLL project as
>   the Visual Studio solution startup project to debug the workflow using
>   F5. You must also set the path to the host application in the workflow
>   DLL project’s Start external program property.
>
> To set a startup project in Solution Explorer, right-click the project
>   name and select Set as StartUp Project. To set the path to the host in
>   the Start external program property, double-click the workflow
>   project’s Properties node in Solution Explorer and select the Debug
>   tab. Under Start Action, select Start external program and enter the
>   path to the .exe file that is hosting the workflow you want to debug.
>
> If the host application is set as the startup project, only the Visual
>   Studio debugger is invoked for debugging; the Visual Studio 2010
>   Debugger for Windows Workflow Foundation is not invoked. If the Visual
>   Studio debugger is used, only C# or Visual Basic code breakpoints are
>   hit; breakpoints set in the workflow designer are not hit. For
>   example, a breakpoint that you set on a ParallelActivity activity in
>   the designer is hit if the Visual Studio 2010 Debugger for Windows
>   Workflow Foundation is used, but not when you use the Visual Studio
>   debugger.

See if it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the application and definition are in the same project. And I'm using WF4 which is a complete remake from WF3.